# JsDoc Typing In FabricJS

Tags: fabricjs, jsdoc

I'm having trouble with some typing errors when calling `removeWithUpdate` on the response to `canvas.getActiveObject()`

```
canvas.getActiveObject().removeWithUpdate(obj)
```

The error is `Property 'removeWithUpdate' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

The code works, I may just do a @ts-ignore here, but what are some other options?

I'm using JsDoc loosely and in key complexity spots, but I am running production build through the ts-checker in webpack.

Casting works fine, but in that case I'd rather just do an @ts-ignore:

```js
 /** @type {{removeWithUpdate: function}} */
            const active = /** @type {*} */ (this.canvas.getActiveObject())
            active.removeWithUpdate(obj)
```